# Drag and drop crossfading using Javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fading

I'm looking to drag and drop a png image over another png image in the fashion of a cross fade using Javascript. I researched a little and could only come across similar situations but the ones I found were mostly automatic (couldn't do manual drag and drop) and they were fading, not cross fading.
I'm just wondering, does anyone have any ideas as to what is the best way to approach this situation and try to develop this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Jqueryui draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

for that.

and you can use  [jquery effects](http://jqueryui.com/docs/show/) too  along with it

or for effects this plugin might help you [Jquery cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)

or check this [cross fade image](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/)

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the cross fade, I achieve this by having two div elements, positioned absolutely (`position:absolute;`), occupying the same area. One has `opacity:0;`, the other has `opacity:1;`. All you need to do then is have a toggle function which fades one out while the other fades in.

Comment: Sounds interesting! I might use this for another project of mine. Thanks!